# generate reliable pseudorandom number

Tags: ios, random, srand

I want to write a multiplayer game on iOS platform. The game relied on random numbers that generated dynamically in order to decide what happen next. But it is a multiplayer game so this "random number" should be the same for all device for every player in order to have a consistent game play.

Therefor I need a good reliable pseudorandom number generator that if I seed it a same number first than it will keep generate same sequences of random number on all device (iPad/iPhone/iPodTouch) and all OS version.

Looks like `srand` and `rand` will do the job for me but I am not sure does `rand` guarantee to generate same number on all device across all OS version? Otherwise is any good pseudorandom number generate algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the C standard (and Objective C is a thin layer on top of C so this should still hold):

> If srand is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated.

There's *no* guarantee that different implementations (or even different versions of the *same* implementation) will give a consistent sequence based on the seed. If you *really* want to guarantee that, you can code up your own linear congruential generator, such as the example one in the standard itself:

```
// RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767.
static unsigned long int next = 1;
void srand(unsigned int seed) { next = seed; }
int rand(void) {
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}
```

And, despite the fact that there are better generators around, the simple linear congruential one is generally more than adequate, unless you're a statistician or cryptographer.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a seed value to rand then it should consistently provide the same sequence of pseudorandom numbers. You can also try arc4random().

Comment: That's true for a given implementation but not necessarily all implementations.